# Orderable z3c RelationList widget

Tags: plone, zope, dexterity, z3c.form

Is there any RelationList/RelationChoice widget for z3c.form which supports items ordering?

Answer (score 1):

z3c.formwidget.query supports ordered relations since version 0.7:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.formwidget.query

To change the ordering of existing relations the user has to remove/re-add items though. You can use javascript for a more convinient reordering of the items (jQuery UI sortable worked for me pretty well).